# Matlab xlsread: force empty cells to be read as NaN

Tags: matlab, io, xlsread

I need to import data from a square region (10 by 10 cells) on an Excel sheet into Matlab.

All data in the region are numerical, but some outer rows and columns of the region are empty.

In Matlab I still want to have a 10 by 10 matrix of doubles with NaNs in places where there are empty cells in Excel (also in outer rows and columns).

If I use xlsread then empty outer rows and columns are automatically truncated.

Needless to say that all should be done automatically without the knowledge how many empty outer rows and columns are there.

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you check the second output argument of `xlsread`?

Comment: @Daniel, yep, it is empty.

Comment: Found on matlab central:
num = xlsread(filename, 'range');
[m n] = size(num);
num(end+1,:) = nan(1,n);

Comment: @C.Colden I think you manually pad num with an additional row at the end, but what if you do not know how many outer extra NaNs rows and columns you need to attach because everything should be automatic.

Comment: I do not fully understand your problem. What do you mean with outer rows/columns. Could you edit your question and add some examples?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your 10 by 10 spreadsheet's first row and column and last row and column are empty (like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTVAA.png)). Using:

```matlab
[num,txt,raw] = xlsread('myfile.xlsx',1,'A1:J10'); % Read input.
```

will return:

```
num   8x8 double
txt   0x0 cell
raw   10x10 cell
```

In `num`, non-scalar leading rows and columns are automatically truncated, while in `txt` any numerical values are omitted. However, `raw` contains all information, so it can be used to extract the numerical values:

```matlab
raw(cellfun(@ischar,raw)) = {NaN}; % Set non-scalar values to missing.
A = cell2mat(raw); % Convert to matrix.
```

Comment: Why is this not implemented in a more user-friendly way? If I tell Matlab to read a certain range like above, it assumes that I am wrong and in fact, it thinks I mean the 8x8 matrix. I haven't found this in all excel packages for R, Python or Gams and I assume this will be also the case for other languages. If I look this up in the Matlab documentation, 

I only see: _[num,txt,raw] = xlsread(___) additionally returns the text fields in cell array txt, and both numeric and text data in cell array raw, using any of the input arguments in the previous syntaxes_.